# D3 Pan and Zoom chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, zooming, pan

I'm having trouble adding the ability to pan and zoom a D3.js chart. I've tried multiple approaches, but can't seem to figure it out.

Theoretically, I'd like to zoom effect when a user either scrolls or uses the mouse to drag between graph pieces. And use the pan effect for when a user drags outside of those areas.

Any thoughts or examples on how to do this? A bit of code for where I'm at now is below.

Thanks,

```
    addPanAndZoom: function(chart, chartType, chartMargin, numXLabels, svg, redraw) {
        // graph dom elements
        var rect = svg.select('rect'),
            paths = svg.select('path');

        // Chart dimensions
        var width = Number(rect.attr("width")),
            height = Number(rect.attr("height"));

        var xDomain = chart.xDomain;

        var numXTicks = numXLabels - 1,
            numYTicks = 10;

        var scaleExtent = 10;

        var x = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([0, width]).domain([0, numXTicks]),
            y = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([0, height]).domain([height, 0]);

        var make_x_axis = function () {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                .tickValues(numXTicks);
        };

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickValues(numXTicks);

        var make_y_axis = function () {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .tickValues(numYTicks);
        };

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .tickValues(numYTicks);

        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .x(x)
            .y(y)
            .scaleExtent([1, scaleExtent])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        svg.call(zoom);

        function zoomed() {
            console.log('zoomed');

            var translate = zoom.translate(),
                scale = zoom.scale();

            var xTranslate = translate[0],
                yTranslate = translate[1];

            // set min and max axis values
            var totalWidth = width * scale;

            var min = Math.max(0, numXTicks * (xTranslate / totalWidth)),
                max = Math.min(numXTicks, numXTicks * ((-xTranslate + width) / totalWidth));

            // minor tweak -- snap min/max to end if close enough
            if (min / numXTicks < 0.05) min = 0;
            if (max / numXTicks > 0.95) max = numXTicks;

            // set the domain for the x axis
            xDomain([min, max]);

            // redraw chart
            redraw();
        }
    }
```